# Saving changes in php artisan tinker

Tags: php, laravel, sequelpro, tinker

I am working on a Laravel project. First, have run a migration and created a Blueprint for the table:

```
php artisan migrate
```

I edited the migration by creating a Schema with the following structure

```
Schema::create('donations', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->string('email');
          $table->string('about');
          $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
```

Next, I created the model named Donation using tinker editor

```
php artisan make:model Donation
```

However, I was unable to save my changes and populate my newly created table, as when I tried to save my edits I run into an error. Below, I have posted my edits and the error I got.

```
$donation = new App\Donation;
=> App\Donation {#2934}

>>> $donation->email = 'pele@gmail.com'
=> "pele@gmail.com"
>>> $donation->about = '1M donation'
=> "1M donation"

>>> $donation 
=> App\Donation {#2934
     email: "pele@gmail.com",
     about: "1M donation",

 $donation->save();
```

The error

```
Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `donations` (`email`, `about`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (pele@gmail.com, 1M donation, 2019-06-10 12:19:04, 2019-06-10 12:19:04))'
```

Comment: `public $timestamps = false;` inside model

Comment: @DrakulaPredator Do you mean that your code should go into tinker editor?

Comment: I don't know, I mean, edit your model is created, and write my snippet there and check

Comment: I get this error after adding your code to tinker editor with unsaved changes: PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC on line 1

Comment: This problem I solved by adding my snippet inside a model class. I don't know about Tinker.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, your migration file is not using the `$table->timestamps()` method, which will create both `created_at` and `updated_at` date-time fields.

When trying to save a new record using tinker, the model is expecting to save both the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. If you would like to go forward without having a `updated_at` field, add the following to your `Donation` model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Else, you can solve the issue by replacing:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
```

With:

```
$table->timestamps();
```

**Note:** This would make the `created_at` field not nullable, meaning it will always expect a value. However, on create/save this will be set automatically.

Answer (score 2):

using Eloquent models by default assumes you have both created_at and updated_at fields in your table, but in your case you are only using created_at field.
so when using the model to save the record it tries to save the updated_at but you don`t have one.
to fix this you can disable the timestaps by

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This change to my Model solved my issue:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Donation extends Model
{
 public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Also, I had to exit the tinker editor and then run the following commands in order to make it work:

```
$donation = new App\Donation();
$donation->email = 'random@gmail.com'
$donation->about = '1M from Pele'
$donation->save();
```

Ultimately, reentering tinker and adding changes from scratch after adding new line to the model helped.

Answer (score 0):

you have make a mistake in column name when you enter the data and the name of the column doesn't match the column name in the table